# After adding button area is not reseting ,showing previous area

Tags: angularjs

> Blockquote
>   After adding(+) fields  the area is not resetting its showing previous area only.
>   Blockquote

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.addNewChoice = function () { var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choices' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0});};
$scope.removeChoice = function () { var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {$scope.choices.splice(lastItem);}};
$scope.sum = function () { var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (choice) {
               sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2;
          }); return sum;}
$scope.Getarea = function () {
                $scope.total = +document.getElementById("total").value;};
    $scope.$watch($scope.sum, function (value) {
       $scope.total = value;});});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <body><div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <form  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">   <br>  {{$index + 1}} : Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.l2"  />ft Breadth: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.b2"  />ft
                    Area:  <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="total" placeholder="Area"  ng-model="total" ng-change="Getarea()">sqft <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button><button  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> </br> </form>
               <p class="bold">Area to be treated:</p> <h1>{{( + total + ( + total * 0.05)) | number:2}}<span class="small-text"> </span></h1>
          </div> <script src="ATT.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please dont post uglified code

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of `addNewChoice` function, that way the ng-repeat will lookup choices array.

But, looking again at your code, the problem is that you're using `ng-model="total"` in your input. In order to make it work, you need to change it to something like `ng-model="choice.total"` and update that value `Getarea()` method. Also, i'd pass `choice` to that function, so your function will affect to correct choice each time it gets called.